# Regex: Finding duplicates in string

Tags: regex

https://regex101.com/r/kBxa7R/2

I have following regex: `\b(\w+) \b(?=.*\b\1)`

I need to remove all duplicates in string. So for instance:

`Mike Tyson 1. Street 1234 Vietnam ML(12534/97632) Mike Tyson 1234 1. Street Vietnam ML(12534/97632)`

should results in:

`Mike Tyson 1. Street 1234 Vietnam ML(1234/97632)`

I already know why it fails, but I do not know how to fix it. I only look for `\w+` and therefore "`1.`" or "`ML(156746/615893)`" is not beeing found. But when I add these missing characters manually or replace the whole statement by `.+` weird stuff is going on.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
(?<!\S)(\S+)\h+(?=(?:\S+\h+)*?\1(?!\S))
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kBxa7R/9)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\S)`: Lookbehind to assert that we don't have a non-space at previous position
- `(\S+)`: Match 1+ non-whitespace character and capture this in group #1
- `\h+`: Match 1+ whitespace
- `(?=`: Start positive lookahead

  - `(?:\S+\h+)*?`: Lazily match 0 more groups where each group consists of 1+ non-whitespace characters followed by 1+ space
  - `\1`: Back reference for group #1
  - `(?!\S)`: Must not be followed by a non-whitespace to avoid partial matches
- `)`: End positive lookahead

---

Casimir has made a very good suggestion in comments of using verb `(*SKIP)` for PCRE flavors as well. This appears to be more efficient as per regex101 website:

```
~(\S+) \h+ (*SKIP) (?= (?>\S+\h+)*? \1 (?!\S) )~x
```

Comment: I have no clue why it works, but I kinda does. Thank you in advance. Could please have look at: https://regex101.com/r/kBxa7R/6 again? There is just two minor issues left. 
1. In the street, the . is replaced even when the number is not the same (represented in line 2 in regex101)
2. For the XX(XXXX/XXXXX) part, it should ony replace if the whole string is the same (represented in line 2 and 3 in regex101)

Comment: Just for my culture. Can't we just use \b(\S+) instead of (?<!\S)(\S+)    ?

Comment: Two other versions: https://regex101.com/r/Npoe1G/1 https://regex101.com/r/Npoe1G/2

Comment: Wow, both of them are really good ones @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: @Vincent: Please try `(?<!\S)(\S+)\h+(?=(?:\S+\h+)*?\1(?!\S))` as per suggestion of Casimir. And yes we can use `\b` instead of `(?<!\S)` also but I think `\b` might be tad slower.